# Odd Microsoft Edge scrollbar causing Jquery animation shaking the whole page

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to display an image that fill the whole page. I also put an element (a white div) on the image. When hover on the element, the div's size will be increase and decrease when hover off.

It's working with no problem on Chrome, safari and Firefox.

However, I found when I open the page on Microsoft Edge, when dragging the browser to certain size - the scroll bar is just about to showing up but display as very strange light grey. If I hover the element, the whole page is start shaking because the browser seems to adjusting the scroll bar.

You can see the problem here:

https://codepen.io/HelenIT/pen/xxEaeJJ

And here is my code for HTML, CSS and JQuery:

```
 <div>
       <img src="~/Images/test.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
       <div class="csTest">
        Hover on me
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.csTest {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    background-color: white;
  
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".csTest").hover(function () {

    console.log("over");
    $(".csTest").animate(
        {
            height: 200,
            width: 200
        }, 700);


}, function () { //hover off
        console.log("off");
        $(".csTest").animate(
            {
                height: 100,
                width: 100
            }, 700);

});
```

This is my first post, if I am posting not right, I would really appreciate your help.
I also really appreciate anyone's help because I am kind of desperate on how to solve the problem.

Here is the image on when the problem happens, what is the scroll bar looks like

[link]https://rmssdstorage.blob.core.windows.net/www/error_1.png

Comment: I don't see the problem on Edge, it seems to behave the same as FF and Chrome on Windows 10. What sort of size window makes it happen? (I've tried several) - it may be that the non-existence of the image means the problem doesn't show - could you check that the pen does show the problem for you?

Comment: It's kind of tricky to reproduce the problem. But it is can be reproduce in Codepen, you need to drag the size to make the scroll bar between display or not display in Edge, there is a certain point that the scroll bar is displayed in flat grey. At that point if you move the mouse on the white element, you can see the shaking problem. Here is a screenshot of that the scroll bar looks like:     [link]https://rmssdstorage.blob.core.windows.net/www/error_1.png

Comment: It's very strange, for me it's the other way round. I can replicate the shaking in Chrome, but not on Edge. On Edge, I found that point where the scrollbar container appears (1042px to 1054px), then hovered over the white square, but the shaking didn't occur. I then tried it in Chrome (963px to 978px), and it shook. I noticed that for Chrome, that within this range of pixels, the scrollbar container disappears for every alternate pixel. So 963px, it shows. 964px it doesn't. 965px it shows, etc. But with my Edge, it shows with each width within the range so it appears smooth

Comment: @MichaelvE I've now consistently managed to get it to shake on Chrome and Edge - it's definitely at the point that the system is deciding between showing the vertical scrollbar and not. (i.e the greyed out scrollbar shows/doesn't show/shows etc). Unable to get it to that intermediate state on Firefox - it never shows the greyed-out scrollbar and the animation does not produce jumpiness.